# Excel VBA - Using a variable to set the pivot table datafield function

Tags: vba, excel, dynamic, pivot-table

I'm trying to create custom reports using VBA created pivot tables and one of the parts I am having trouble with is setting the datafield to be based on what he user desires.

For example:
I have a drop down menu that displays each type of PivotFields function (sum, min max etc.)  and depending on what the user selects it is stored as a string variable.

When I run my code:

```
Dim valueXL As String
valueXL = xlSum

With Worksheets(sheetPivotName).PivotTables(sheetPivotName).PivotFields(valueType)
.Function = valueXL
.NumberFormat = "$#,##0.00"
End With
```

I get an error, however, if I replace .Function = valueXL with .Function = xlSum it works correctly.

Is there any way to dynamically set the .Function value?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As xlSum is a numeric Excel constant you should change valueXL to integer

```
Dim valueXL As Integer
valueXL = xlSum
```

or use direct the constant in your code

```
With Worksheets(sheetPivotName).PivotTables(sheetPivotName).PivotFields(valueType)
  .Function = xlSum
  .NumberFormat = "$#,##0.00"
End With
```

Comment: or use `CInt(valueXL)`... still it makes no sense that `valueXL` is defined as string :/

Comment: Thanks for this , I had no idea xlSum and those values were treated as integers and not strings!

Answer (score 0):

I found a possible solution, which is using the Evaluate function, however I was wondering if there were any other solutions?

If not I can select this as the answer.